# Use HTTP module to redirect user to another site for custom authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, httpmodule

How can I use HTTP Module to redirect the initial request to another site for Custom authentication ? Can a session information be retrieved in HTTP Module?

Comment: What is the HTTP Module you're talking about? Can you link us to what it is?

Comment: if you are asking about authentication using google or facebook than you have to check those sites for documentation and achieve the authentication functionality using OAuth protocol.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I am looking for Custom Http Module which can intercept the IIS request and redirect the user to another site for authentication.

Comment: @Sami tag member you writing message with `@` and name without soaces. StackOverflow will show the suggests to autofill. It will notify the target member via messages inbox.

Comment: First, how did you customize authentication? and whether it can be called back? what is your purpose? normally, you can get session information as long as you get the session id.